# python string as variable reporting nan

Tags: python, regex, string, pandas, python-3.7

I am finding my name content/ variable value inside one document with the below:

```
find_name = re.search(r'^[^\d]*', clean_content)

Name = find_name.group(0)
NameUp = Name.upper()
```

Which works fine... *it equals `DAN STEPP` as needed.*

I then open up an excel file:

```
data1 = pd.read_excel(config.Excel1)
```

Pass into a data frame, give them headers; all this works:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data1)
header = df.iloc[0]
```

Now when I do the search; with the below it returns `nan` erroneously

```
row_numberd1 = df[df['Member Name'].str.contains(NameUp)].index.min()
```

With my `NameUp` var, which equals `DAN STEPP` in value when I print and test, so it does contain correct value. However, when I use the variable above to search, I get `nan`.

When I replace NameUp with `"DAN STEPP`" like that, ***not using the variable, it becomes found*** - any thoughts on this? i.e. '`.str.contains("DAN STEPP")`'

Comment: One thing: you can change `df[df['Member Name'].str.contains(NameUp)].index.min()` to `df['Member Name'].str.contains(NameUp).idxmax()`.

Answer (score 0):

Would you mind doing repr(NameUp)? It's slightly different from str(NameUp) in that it will print exactly what's in the string. Besides that I have no idea what to make of

```
row_numberd1 = df[df['Member Name'].str.contains(NameUp)].index.min()
```

I don't use pandas but that's up... that's a lot of stuff in one line? I would check each process individually as to see what's wrong. Since you said that it was throwing the wrong thing with the NameUp variable, I would deconstruct `df['Member Name'].str.contains(NameUp)` to see what it spits out, and make sure that it's consistent with your testing. Have you tried with any other names/values?

TL;DR:  if the variable is not working, and manually inputting the string is, there is one of two things happening. Either the two strings are different in some minor way, or the process of which you are testing the two are not the same.